# How to exclude url in subsequent requests in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I created a test script by [BlazeMeter chrome extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium). In my test there is simple GET request fo getch the home page:

[image]

It redirects user to another page and makes other GET requests to get static assets. I would like to exclude url `cloudfront` from subsequent http calls. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special field under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)) which allows you to filter out the unwanted domains for example if they're "external"

[image]

More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)